# Can / should you put a 28C tire on a rim with an ETRTO of 622 x 14

Tags: road-bike, tire, wheels

Setting aside the questions of frame and brake clearance for the moment, my question is whether or not I can install 28C tires on my rims which have an ETRTO of 622x14.  I currently have 23C tires on the bike, which is what the bike came with originally, but am thinking of moving to 25C or even 28C tires but am not sure if 28C is too wide for these rims.

And the next question is, even if it does fit on the rim will it create a safety or performance issue to put 28C's on these rims?

My goal is to move from my old school 23C's to something with less rolling resistance and that give a little more forgiving ride.  Just want to be sure I do it safely and wisely.

Comment: Take your pick: https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk028rdRe0ltty7xp3CMrGJr6vrHZOA:1591238667353&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=bicycle+tire+width+vs+rim+width&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiiw5T8kefpAhUQt54KHc6NDdsQsAR6BAgIEAE&biw=1096&bih=498

Comment: FWIW, I've found that 28c tires on bikes designed for 23c does generally work, but the clearances become so small that the rims have to be perfectly true and you need to deflate the rear tire to remove from the frame if you have horizontal dropouts. Which is a shame, because there are some really nice 28c tires out there now, that was not the case when these bikes were new. 28c was generally a thick slow "flat proof" tire.

Comment: I put a 28mm on a bike designed for 23, and while there was clearance, there was also tyre rub because bikes flex.  So laterally you still need multiple millimetres of space around the tyre.  It may not be worth doing if your wider tyre abrades your frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no issue with running a 28 on this width rim. In the decades of 23mm tires being the norm and virtually all road rims being 13-15mm internal width, many cyclists rode 28s since it's the widest size many such road bikes can take.

32 is also fine. 35 is about where issues with squirmy feel are perceptible.

Comment: That's what I figured was the case but it doesn't hurt to get confirmation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - a 28c tyre will work on an older narrower rim, but the width can be different.

You may find the following. It appears the new standard is wider tires and wider rims. New rims are 19 not 12-14. So, if you buy a new 700 x 28c tire, you will find it measures 27.8 on a 19 rim but 22.8 on a 14 rim, that's right, less than 23, and it will still weigh like a 28 always did.

This just happened to me. I bought the same model family from the same manufacturer assuming they would measure approximately the same. Turns out the older 28c measures 30.2 on a 19 rim and 28 on a 14 rim. Planned obsolescence at it's best.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The question wasn't about the effective size of a tire, it was simply if the tire would fit (safely) at all.  This might be an informative comment, but it doesn't actually answer the question.  When you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments on other posts; in the meantime you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Manufacturers can't win either way here.
Either they change tyres to be sized appropriately with modern wheels or we end up with a situation where tyres are coming up way bigger than the stated size.  Either way is bad - the customer just wants the size to be what they ordered.

Comment: Welcome - this is interesting and worth preserving, so I can convert to a comment OR you can use [edit] to make this an answer.  I'll try that and you can improve as you see fit.

Comment: How does "planned obsolescence" fit in here?

Comment: @AndyP although I guess manufacturers have more to loose if they take the narrow rims as reference: a wider tire might be problematic on some bikes where frame clearance is by design very small.